# Error when feeding numpy sequence to bidirectional LSTM in Keras

Tags: python, numpy, keras, lstm

I am trying to feed the features extracted from 2 fine-tuned VGG16 (each on a different stream), then for each sequence of 9 data pairs, concatenate their numpy arrays and feed the sequence of 9 outputs (concatenated) to a bi-directional LSTM in Keras.

The problem is that I am running into an error when trying to build the LSTM part. The following shows the generator I wrote to read both RGB and Optical flow streams, extract features and concatenate each pair :

```
def generate_generator_multiple(generator,dir1, dir2, batch_rgb, batch_flow, img_height,img_width):

    print("Processing inside generate multiple")

    genX1 = generator.flow_from_directory(dir1,
                                          target_size = (img_height,img_width),
                                          class_mode = 'categorical',
                                          batch_size = batch_rgb,
                                          shuffle=False 
                                          )

    genX2 = generator.flow_from_directory(dir2,
                                          target_size = (img_height,img_width),
                                          class_mode = 'categorical',
                                          batch_size = batch_flow,
                                          shuffle=False    
                                          )

    while True:

            imgs, labels = next(genX1)
            X1i = RGB_model.predict(imgs, verbose=0)

            imgs2, labels2 = next(genX2)            
            X2i = FLOW_model.predict(imgs2,verbose=0)

            Xi = []
            for i in range(9):
                Xi.append(np.concatenate([X1i[i+1],X2i[i]]))

            Xi = np.asarray(Xi)

            if np.array_equal(labels[1:],labels2)==False:
                print("ERROR !! problem of labels matching: RGB and FLOW have different labels")

            yield Xi, labels2[2]
```

I am expecting the generator to yield a sequence of 9 arrays, so the shape of Xi when I force the loop to run twice is: (9, 14, 7, 512)

When I use while True (like in the code above) and try to call the method to check what it returs, after 3 iterations I get the error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Now, assuming that there is no problem with the generator, I try to feed the data returned by the generator to the bidirectional LSTM like the following:

```
n_frames = 9
seq = 100

Bi_LSTM = Sequential()
Bi_LSTM.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(seq, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25, recurrent_dropout=0.1),input_shape=(n_frames,14,7,512)))
Bi_LSTM.add(GlobalMaxPool1D())
Bi_LSTM.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(100, activation="relu")))
Bi_LSTM.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))
Bi_LSTM.add(Dense(4, activation="relu"))

model.compile(Adam(lr=.00001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

But I keep getting the following error: (the error log is a bit long)

```
InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 2 for 'bidirectional_2/Tile_1' (op: 'Tile') with input shapes: [?,7,512,1], [2].
```

It seems to be caused by this line:

```
Bi_LSTM.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(seq, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25, recurrent_dropout=0.1),input_shape=(n_frames,14,7,512)))
```

I am not sure anymore if the problem is the way I try to build the LSTM, the way I return the data from the generator, or the way I define the input of LSTM.

Thanks a lot for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this error specifically is cause by the following line:

```
input_shape=(n_frames,14,7,512)
```

I was confused about the input for LSTM. Instead to explicitly giving the shape of the input, we just need to specify the dimensions of the input. In my case, this is 3 since the input is a 3D np array. I still have other problems with my code, but for this specific error, the solution is changing that part with:

```
input_shape=(n_frames,3)
```

**Edit:**
When predicting, We need to get the mean of the prediction since LSTM expects a 1D input.

Another issue in my code was the shape of Xi. It needs to be reshaped before yielding it so that it matches the input expected by LSTM.